# tensorflow: logging custom loss function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've written a custom loss function as follows:

```
def distance_loss(y_actual, y_pred):
    return tf.math.sqrt(
            tf.math.add(
                tf.math.pow(
                    tf.math.subtract(y_actual[0], y_pred[0]),
                    tf.constant(2.0)
                ),
                tf.math.pow(
                    tf.math.subtract(y_actual[1], y_pred[1]),
                    tf.constant(2.0)
                )
            )
        )
```

However this is my first time doing this so I don't know how well (or if) this function is working.

Is there any way I can log the inputs and output of this function, as well as the sample it's being called on, so I can manually verify that it's working as intended?

Comment: Why not create variables for each operation and use `tf.print`?

Comment: @AloneTogether because I didn't know `tf.print1 existed! I will try that, thanks. (Btw this is the same model you helped me with previously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.print`:

```py
def distance_loss(y_actual, y_pred):
    x = tf.math.pow(
                    tf.math.subtract(y_actual[0], y_pred[0]),
                    tf.constant(2.0)
                )
    y =  tf.math.pow(
                    tf.math.subtract(y_actual[1], y_pred[1]),
                    tf.constant(2.0)
                )
    loss = tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.add(x, y))
    tf.print('First operation ->', x)
    tf.print('Second operation ->', y)
    tf.print('Loss ->', loss)
    return loss
```

and you will see the values when you call `model.fit(*)`.